# Uber android SDK Not able to book ride, It always loading

Tags: android, uber-api

I am landing in this place, its not showing cab nearby.

Here is configuration builder

```
  configuration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)//Scope.ALL_TRIPS takes the user to browser
            .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS, Scope.HISTORY))
            .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.PRODUCTION)
            .build();
```

I have added redirect URI on Uber developer dashboard too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue was occuring due to invalid uber account, I have created an uber account with just email-ID and I have not linked phone number. When I tried with another uber account which has phone number linked that worked me